# VS Code Ansible "all tasks should be named" warning

Tags: ansible, visual-studio-code, pylint

Upgraded to VS Code 1.54.3 and now getting a warning about "all tasks should be named". Some do have a name and are still getting the warning. Others I need to go back and add the name to. But for now I want to turn this off, but can't find what setting it is.

Comment: Okay it looks like the issus is with the Ansible Extension that is in preview (zbr.vscode-ansible). If it's disabled the errors go away. I guess I need to look there now. Any help would be great.

Comment: That is coming from [`ansible-lint`](https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-lint) and can be configured by putting an [`.ansible-lint` file in your project's directory](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuring.html#configuration-file); as for the "do have a name and are still getting the warning" you'll have to edit your question to show the code that is behaving as you claim in order for anyone to help you